# Question about integrals of an unkown function and then differentiating to it

Tags: integration, derivatives

In my thesis I encountered the following problem: I have an unknown function y(x) and I need to calculate the following combination of integrating and differentiating:
$\frac{d}{dy}\int_0^1\cos(y(x))dx$
Is there a general theory on how to determine such an expression?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign/) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule‎)